# Inquiry vs Enquiry what's the difference?

Tags: british-english, formal-language, academic-writing

Is there a difference between the two words Inquiry and Enquiry when being used in formal writing as the two have been used alternatively in literature. And if not which one should be preferred in formal written communication?

Answer (score 2):

Inquiry is AmE, and Enquiry is BrE.  They are, in reality, the same word with a spelling difference.

This website might help: https://thecontentauthority.com/blog/inquiry-vs-enquiry

Comment: “Inquiry” sounds conventional, but “enquiry” sounds literary.

Comment: In the UK, some people say that a distinction is developing - "inquiry" being used in relation to a formal inquest (i.e., an investigation), and "enquiry" is being used to mean "the act of questioning." This is not a strict rule however.